# How to only display rows with foreignAlias that is set in Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have a list that is pulled from three tables, Department, Type and User.

Displayed like this:

```
Film 
student      Jimmy Stewart
faculty      Cary Grant
```

**from actions.class.php**

```
$this->departments = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Department')
        ->createQuery('a')
        ->orderBy('a.name')
        ->execute();
```

**indexSuccess.php**

```
<?php foreach ($departments as $dept): ?>
      <tr>
        <?php check_for_id() ?>
        <td colspan="4" class="displayDept" valign="top"><?php echo $dept->getName() ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach ($dept->getUsers() as $user): ?>
    <tr>
      <td class="displayInfo" valign="top"><?php echo $user->getType() ?></td>
      <td class="displayInfo" valign="top"><a href="<?php echo $user->getUrl() ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $user->getUrl() ?></a></td>
      <td class="displayInfo" valign="top"><?php echo simple_format_text($user->getDescription()) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

However, this results in the foreach pulling all id's from the department table leaving some empty rows under the Department display. Like this:

```
Photography
student      Keanu Reeves
faculty      Lawrence Fishburn

Drawing

Film 
    student      Jimmy Stewart
    faculty      Cary Grant

Painting

Sculpture
```

Can I remove the departments that do not have a user id?

**UPDATE**

If I am going to use a join, how do I call that in the actions? This is where I am so far, but none of my iterations are working:

```
$this->departments = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Department')
        ->createQuery('a')
        ->leftJoin('a.Users p')
        ->orderBy('a.name ASC')
        ->execute();
```

I'm not sure what it does though. I can understand the WHERE as it would be in traditional php, but I cannot follow the symfony syntax. Am I even close??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it in the query, department joined with users?

**UPDATE**

this is from the top of my head, but it should be something like this:

```
$this->departments = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Department')
        ->createQuery('a')
        ->leftJoin('a.Users p')
        ->groupBy('a.id')
        ->having('COUNT(a.id) > 0')
        ->orderBy('a.name ASC')
        ->execute();
```

Comment: That does not throw an error, but it does not remove the rows with empty user data. I guess I do not understand what the "a" and "p" represent. Should I edit the schema.yml?

Comment: a is the alias for the department table and p for users table.

Answer (score 0):

Vlad had it right, I just made a few tweaks and wanted to post it for others.

**Here is the actions.class.php**

```
$this->departments = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('d.id')
        ->from('Department d')
        ->leftJoin('d.Users u')
        ->groupBy('d.id')
        ->having('COUNT(u.id) > 0')
        ->orderBy('d.name ASC')
        ->execute();
```

I also edited my **schema.yml**

```
Department:
 actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
 columns:
  id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
  name: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }
 relations:
  User: {class: User, local: name, foreign: department_id, foreignAlias: Departments}

Type:
 actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
 columns:
  id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
  name: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }
  user_id: { type: integer(4) }

User:
 actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
 columns:
  id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
  firstname: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
  lastname: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
  email: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }
  department_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
  type_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
  url: { type: string(255), notnull:true }
  description: { type: string(4000) }
 relations:
  Department: { class: Department, local: department_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Users}
  Type: { class: Type, local: type_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Users }
```

And this worked great. Thanks for the further explanation of the alias letters. It is still a bit foggy, since it seems these letters are just made up. I chose d for department and u for users, and I'm not sure if that makes a lick of difference. Thanks @Vlad for the help!

Comment: The letter's don't make any difference. D for department is just fine.